# CORS policy when deleting an item

Tags: angular, spring-boot, cors

[error message in google chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ev8i.png)When I try to delete an item I am getting an error.

When I added spring security to my backend i faced problem with csrf and could not event display my data from database in Angular. So, I made some steps: 
I have added `@WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` into my backend. Later set Interceptor in Angular and after this I was able to load my data using spring security in background.

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
public class SpringSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS,"/**").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                //.formLogin().and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
}
```

Angular part my service with Interceptor

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest} from '@angular/common/http';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler) {
    const username = 'damian';
    const password = 'damian';
    const basicAutHeaderString = 'Basic ' + window.btoa(username + ':' + password);



    request = request.clone(
      {
        setHeaders: {
          Authorization: basicAutHeaderString
        }
      }
    );
    return next.handle(request);
  }


  constructor() { }


}
```

Getting single item from backend:

```
  deleteSingleTodo(id) {
    return this.http.delete<Todo>(`http://localhost:8081/${id}`);
  }
```

My delete method which is triggered by (click) button:

```
  deleteTodo(id) {
    console.log(`delete todo ${id}` )
    this.getDataService.deleteSingleTodo( id).subscribe (
      response => {
        console.log(response);
        this.message = `Delete of Todo ${id} Successful!`;
        this.refreshTodos();
      }
    );
  }

I also provided HTTP_INTERCEPTORS in app.module.ts
 providers: [
    { provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, `useClass: HttpInterceptorService, multi:` true}
```

],`[my error message in google][1]`

Comment: *Please* never add error messages as images. Where do you configure CORS headers ?

Comment: Ok, thank you for advice. I got headers before I set Interceptor, Now when I use Interceptor it should be visible in whole application but only getting all items from databse is working. I am beginner in this full stack world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add below class as CORS configurations

**How it works?**

CORS requests are automatically dispatched to the various HandlerMappings that are registered. They handle CORS preflight requests and intercept CORS simple and actual requests by means of a CorsProcessor implementation (DefaultCorsProcessor by default) in order to add the relevant CORS response headers (such as Access-Control-Allow-Origin).

CorsConfiguration allows one to specify how the CORS requests should be processed: allowed origins, headers and methods among others. This may be provided in various ways

[CORS Doc](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)  [CORS with Spring Boot](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cors)

```
import javax.servlet.Filter;
import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.ServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements Filter,WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) {
      HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
      HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
      System.out.println("WebConfig; "+request.getRequestURI());
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, PUT, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With,observe");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
      response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Authorization");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "responseType");
      response.addHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "observe");
      System.out.println("Request Method: "+request.getMethod());
      if (!(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("OPTIONS"))) {
          try {
              chain.doFilter(req, res);
          } catch(Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
      } else {
          System.out.println("Pre-flight");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST,GET,DELETE,PUT");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
          response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Access-Control-Expose-Headers"+"Authorization, content-type," +
          "USERID"+"ROLE"+
                  "access-control-request-headers,access-control-request-method,accept,origin,authorization,x-requested-with,responseType,observe");
          response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you simply add a filter for applying CORS like as shown below to see if it is working

```
@Component
public class CrossOriginFilter implements Filter {
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CrossOriginFilter.class);

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException {

        // Called by the web container to indicate to a filter that it is being
        // placed into service.
        // We do not want to do anything here.
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse resp, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        log.info("Applying CORS filter");
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) resp;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, Authorization, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, X-Auth-Token, X-CSRF-TOKEN");
        chain.doFilter(req, resp);
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

        // Called by the web container to indicate to a filter that it is being
        // taken out of service.
        // We do not want to do anything here.
    }
}
```